# Calling C function from python using ctypes

Tags: python, c, call, wrapper, ctypes

I have the following C code. I am trying to call this function from Python using `ctypes`:

```
int add ( int arr []) 
{
    printf("number %d \n",arr[0]);
    arr[0]=1;
    return arr[0];
}
```

I compiled this by using:

```
gcc -fpic -c test.c 
gcc -shared -o test.so test.o
```

then put it in `/usr/local/lib`.

Python call for this was:

```
from ctypes import *

lib = 'test.so'
dll = cdll.LoadLibrary(lib)
IntArray5 = c_int * 5
ia = IntArray5(5, 1, 7, 33, 99)
res = dll.add(ia)
print res
```

but I always get some big number like `-1365200`.

I tried also:

```
dll.add.argtypes=POINTER(c_type_int)
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to build around that:

```
lib = 'test.so'
dll = cdll.LoadLibrary(lib)

dll.add.argtypes=[POINTER(c_int)]
#                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#         One argument of type `int *̀

dll.add.restype=c_int
# return type 

res =dll.add((c_int*5)(5,1,7,33,99))
#            ^^^^^^^^^
#       cast to an array of 5 int

print res
```

***Tested both with Python 2.7.3 and 2.6.9***

Answer (score 5):

Instead, try:

```
dll = cdll.LoadLibrary('test.so')
res = dll.add(pointer(c_int(5)))
print res
```